# many=True TypeError object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to fetch the foreign key values in PUT and GET but while using the `many=True` I am getting error `TypeError object is not iterable`.
Here are following the my snippets.

I have two models called *MasterStatus* and *MasterType*. In MasterType I have foreign key values of *MasterStatus*.

**models.py**

```
class MasterType(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    type_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    fk_status = models.ForeignKey(MasterStatus)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s' % (self.type_name)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'master_type'
```

In serializer I am using the `many=True` to get the nested values of foreignkey. Here I have used PrimaryKeyRelatedField serializer.

**serializer.py**

```
class MasterTypeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):     
    fk_status = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=MasterStatus.objects.all(),many=True)   
    class Meta:
        model = MasterType
        fields = ('id', 'type_name', 'fk_status', 'last_modified_date', 'last_modified_by')
        depth = 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to the problem, but why is `MasterTypeSerializer.Meta.model = MasterRepaymentType`? Whats the deifinition of this `MasterRepaymentType` model?

Comment: sorry mistakely typed. i have corrected the MasterRepaymentType to MasterType

Answer (score 0):

`ForeignKey` links to a single MasterStatus instance, therefore it is not many.

Your serializers should look something like this:

```
class MasterTypeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):     
    fk_status = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=MasterStatus.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = MasterRepaymentType

class MasterStatusSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):     
    fk_type = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset= MasterRepaymentType.objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MasterStatus
```

Note that `many` is used on the `fk_type` field as a `MasterStatus` has many `MasterRepaymentType`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to get the nested values of MasterStatus Model in MasterType?